# Frontend design difference between VS2017 chrome (debug) and Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, visual-studio-2017

I deployed my local version and viewed it on Google Chrome and noticed differences in the font size, position of elements and the layout.

Example: 
[image: 1]] 
The left part of the image is Google Chrome running on Windows 10 and the right part is the built in Chrome that runs when I debug the project.

CSS & JS are minified in the release but match the development versions...

Microsoft Edge looks the same as Google Chrome (left part)

Libraries:

```
"jQuery": "3.2.1",
"bootstrap": "v4.0.0-alpha.6",
"bootstrap-validator": "v0.11.9",
"signalr": "v2.2.2",
"cookie": "v1.2.2"
```

Includes:

```
<environment names="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/tether/dist/css/tether.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/tether/dist/css/tether-theme-basic.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/tether/dist/css/tether.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/tether/dist/css/tether-theme-basic.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</environment>
```

CSS code that applies font family (site.css):

```
body {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #555;
}
```

After inspecting the  element I noticed that on the dev version, the element is styled with a border loaded from bootstrap.css.

However on the release version the border is missing because the CSS is loaded from bootstrap/reboot.scss.

[image: 2]]

Still investigating...

Comment: impossible to know from an image

Comment: @epascarello atleast provide me with a way to increase the quality of the post instead of just blatantly downvoting and commenting saying that it's impossible to help (and it clearly isn't since someone already provided me with a possible answer down below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is, like said in comments: "impossible to know from an image". However I'm going to try:

There are obviously multiple things that are "off".

- Different fonts, see inputs.
- Different paddings, see forms.
- Different markup, see horizontal line right image (and black bar on top).

Long story short: It looks like a different stylesheet is being used.

This make me believer that a different stylesheet IS being used. So you need to check the next steps.

- Are you looking at a cached version? Try putting chrome in incognito mode, flush cache etc...
- Are preprocessors being run, is everything compiled OK? (If appliccable.)
- Is your deployment successful?, did you run required preprocessor on deployment (if needed)? Did you perform a cache bust at the deployment target?

Please inspect the page and validate the stylesheets match.

Comment: Turned out to be a version mismatch between bootstrap and the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Usually browsers use `Arial,Times New Roman,Courier New`, As their defualt fonts. however it can be difference in other OS (for example chrome use Helvetica instead of Arial in Mac OS ).

users can change the default browsers fonts also.

Do you use any specific font? check your font-family, if it not used the Standard fonts, make sure your fonts files are in correct path in release version of your website.

Comment: The font is applied to the body: `font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;`

Comment: I think your Georgia font is missing or corrupted and somehow the chrome can't render it, so it replaced with the next font. try to re-install the Georgia font and try again.

Comment: I reinstalled the Georgia font but no dice, am I aloud to give my website link here? If so that might be a bit more help in diagnosing my issue.

Comment: Not sure if you can send your own website link or not ( Probably u can't ) but if you share your CSS file in some online editor like jsfiddle it can be helpful

Comment: Well, I can see that you use bootstrap library, so your css can be override by the bootstrap. I mean not just body, your other html tags.  if that is the case, u need to use Specificity to override your style over the third party css files. Specificity is the means by which browsers decide which CSS property values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be applied. or ( it's not a good practice ) you can use !important for your font-family in all sections which needed.

Comment: Turned out to be a version mismatch between bootstrap and the cache...thanks for all your help.